# shift between different objects in Blender using game engine

Tags: python, blender, blender-2.50

i m working with game Engine(blender)..
there are several objects and i need to shift between them on external input (potentiometer).. need functions(python) that can help me shift between objects(cube, sphere, etc)..

Answer (score 0):

see [the Blender Python API docs](http://www.blender.org/documentation/250PythonDoc/) (specifically the Application Modules -> Data Access(bpy.data) section).

Comment: thank you.
but what abt 2.49..
i hv not started using 2.5's yet .. but plan to in the near future..
another query: should i stick to 2.49 as of now till 2.5x is out or start with these beta versions?

Comment: @parin: Ask new questions in new questions, not comments.

Comment: @parin: As far as I know, the beta versions are quite stable, so I think it would be safe to start using them.